# iTunes shows that iPhone has photos, whereas 'Photos' app shows iPhone has no photos

Tags: iphone, itunes, photos

iTunes shows that my iPhone holds 2,061 photos.

[image: iTunes storage bar shows iPhone holds 2,061 photos.]

However the 'Photos' app [image: 'Photos' app icon] shows that my iPhone has no photos.

[image: 'Photos' app shows iPhone has no photos.]

Which is correct? Why the discrepancy?

---

iMac: macOS Sierra, Version 10.12.4
iPhone: iPhone 4, Version 7.1.2 (11D257)
iTunes: 12.6.0.100
Photos: Version 2.0 (3150.4.120)

Comment: @grgarside: There is no 'Storage  & iCloud Usage' item on the Settings → General page.

Comment: Oops, it was different on iOS 7: Settings → General → Usage → Photos & Camera?

Comment: @grgarside: Camera Roll ... 0 bytes, Photo Library ... 2.2 GB, Photo Stream ... 1.9 KB.